# Is there a way to customize marquee on a HTML table to reduce the scroll delay?

Tags: javascript, html, css, marquee

I'm getting data from an API and I would want to display it on a table. However, this table has a marquee scrolling feature.

The contents should display up as shown on the sample code. That works very well.

The challenge is the `scroll delay`, I would like to display the records, then delay for say 3 seconds then start the loop again.

At the moment, the delay starts after around 80 seconds, guess it's the default?

Hold on, I know marquee is Deprecated, however, it works for this case.

Does anyone know how to go about it?

```js
var response = [
{
"collected_received": 805,
"tested": 526,
"perc_less_1000": 0.8768267,
"rejected": 1
},
{
"collected_received": 788,
"tested": 1933,
"perc_less_1000": 0.9077469,
"rejected": 0
},
{
"collected_received": 114,
"tested": 2342,
"perc_less_1000": 0.9503951,
"rejected": 16
},
{
"collected_received": 492,
"tested": 767,
"perc_less_1000": 0.8912732,
"rejected": 7
},
{
"collected_received": 186,
"tested": 909,
"perc_less_1000": 0.9170404,
"rejected": 1
},
{
"collected_received": 115,
"tested": 378,
"perc_less_1000": 0.931694,
"rejected": 1
},
{
"collected_received": 26,
"tested": 368,
"perc_less_1000": 0.9466292,
"rejected": 0
}
];


var trHTML = '';

$.each(response, function (i, item) {

trHTML += '<tr><td width="130px"><div style="width: 35px;border-radius: 0.1vw; text-align:center; border: 0.1vw rgba(255,255,255,.7) solid;font-size: 0.8em; margin: 0.1vw; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">' + item.collected_received + '</div></td><td width="90px"><div style="width: 35px;border-radius: 0.1vw;text-align:center; border: 0.1vw rgba(255,255,255,.7) solid;font-size: 0.8em; margin: 0.1vw; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">' + item.tested + '</div></td><td width="130px"><div style="width: 35px;border-radius: 0.1vw;text-align:center; border: 0.1vw rgba(255,255,255,.7) solid;font-size: 0.8em; margin: 0.1vw; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">' + item.perc_less_1000.toFixed(1) + '</div></td><td width="90px"><div style="width: 35px;border-radius: 0.1vw;text-align:center; border: 0.1vw rgba(255,255,255,.7) solid;font-size: 0.8em; margin: 0.1vw; padding:0px 0px 0px 0px;">' + item.rejected + '</div></td></tr>';

});
$('#records_table').append(trHTML);
```

```css
.marquee {
    top: 6em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 140s linear 0s infinite;
}

.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        top: 40em
    }
    100% {
        top: -300em
    }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="row contain"
   style="background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.15); margin:2px; height:150vh; max-height:94vh;border-radius: 0.9vw;">
   <div class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-condensed table-striped table-sm" style="color: white;"
         id="table_fixed">
         <thead>
            <tr>
               <th width="130px">Received</th>
               <th width="90px"> Tested </th>
               <th width="130px">Total (%)</th>
               <th width="90px">Rejected </th>
            </tr>
         </thead>
      </table>
   </div>
   <div class="table-responsive" id="contain">
      <table class="marquee table table-condensed table-striped table-sm" style="color: white;truespeed:10;"
         id="records_table">
         <tbody>
         </tbody>
      </table>
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, there is no option to set the delay of next iteration but we can manage it through the small changes in CSS as below, please try with this CSS

```
.marquee {
    top: 6em;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 20s linear 0s infinite;

}

.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        top: 30em;
    }
    100% {
        top: -30em;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no css property to delay between iterations. So we can give that gap in animation itself. Here is the math:

(Delay ÷ Total Time)*100 = Start Percentage

You want to delay for 3s so, we can start our animation at (3÷Total Time)*100.

I have taken an example for total time being 9s so.
We will start the animation at ((3÷9)*100) = 33%

This will delay the animation by 3s and take 6s to complete the animation.

Here is the code:

```css
.marquee {
    top: 100%;
    position: relative;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    animation: marquee 9s linear infinite;
}

.marquee:hover {
    animation-play-state: paused;
}

@keyframes marquee {
    0% {
        top: 100%
    }
    33% {
        top: 100%
    }
    100% {
        top: -100%;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thank you for the reply. Quick one, can the total time be something like 90seconds and still achieve the same? I mean the total display time. 6 seconds is too fast to read from the scrolls.

Comment: You just do the math, if it is 90s then change the start percentage to 3.3%. It will give a 3s delay accordingly. If the answer solves your problem, please consider accepting and upvoting the answer. Thank you.